Supress / hide / discard output without buffering to RAM
How can I tell PHP to discard all output without wasting RAM buffering the output?
I thought this would be a simple and basic feature in PHP, but it doesn't seem to exist.  I am trying to include() a PHP file that has significant output, but also sets some variables.  I only want the variables this time, not the large output.  In Unix this would just be the very basic command &> /dev/null, yet it seems impossible to do the equivalent from within PHP.
It's seems pretty crazy that PHP doesn't support this with a standard ob_ function such as ob_discard() or ob_null_buffering() or similar.  It seems nonsensical to save a buffer to RAM if it will just be discarded after.
Are my only options to:

Modify the entire included file to not output anything when called in this context
Be forced to take a hit to RAM using ob_start() and then ob_end_clean()


The second parameter to ob_start is chunk_size, could you set that to a small enough value (maybe one that doesn’t flush too often, but also uses a reasonable/minimal amount of memory) with a callback that doesn’t flush too nothing with the buffer?

@ChrisHaas: I do not really understand what you wrote.  Wouldn't setting a small buffer size just mean that PHP outputs the content after that small buffer size is filled?  What do you mean by "doesn’t flush too nothing with the buffer"?  Are you suggesting I can use a callback to discard the small buffer at regular intervals?  How would I go about doing that?

I disagree. I hardly find it "crazy" that PHP doesn't have a feature that is needed by virtually no one. I would rather call that word a code that defines some symbols and outputs them in the same file. And of course your best bet is to rewrite it into two files, where one would define some symbols and another would use them. Then just include the former in your current code. What is the amount of RAM in question anyway?

@YourCommonSense: What do you mean by "I would rather call that word a code that defines some symbols and outputs them in the same file."  Call what word?  What do you mean a code?  What symbols are you talking about?  The amount of RAM isn't really relevant, it is variable, could be 1MB.  But if a lot of site users are hitting it, it adds up.  Apparently it is possible keep the buffer small and keep dropping it with a callback, I'm trying to figure that out now.

@YourCommonSense: To add to my question, it is extremely common for PHP coders to use ob_start() and ob_end_clean() to discard output they do not want to use.  But if the coder already knows they will not be using the captured data, why would anyone want to waste resources buffering it?  Anyone that cares about server efficiency doesn't want to waste RAM without reason.

Also, can someone let me know why the question is getting downvotes and requests to close?  It's a legitimate question, doesn't violate any rules, is broadly relevant, and is on-topic.

Nowhere it's extremely common to write a deliberately useless code. It's as common as taking with you a dozen of bricks when you commute, and then just discarding them on your destination. If you don't need some output, then you write a code that just doesn't output anything. While what is relatively common is  to use ob_start() and ob_end_clean() to store the output for some other use, like to use it in another expression.

What is "extremely common" in reality you may check here. You define variables in one file and use them in another. A very useful approach which stems from a more generic principle

Why does PHP need to support this feature if developers can control the output? Why don't you think that it seems nonsensical to output anything if it will just be discarded after.

As noted in the comments, per the documentation you can just set a chunk_size on the buffer and use a custom callback. As long as you don't return false, nothing should be emitted then.
ob_start(fn() => null, chunk_size: 5);

echo 'Nothing happens with this';

Demo: https://3v4l.org/kGPAX
In the demo I'm returning null. That is not /dev/null but I think it helps the mental model when visually scanning this. I'm also using 5 for the chunk_size in the demo, but there may or may not be consequences of setting it too low. I would pick something reasonable, maybe 1M?
